# Scanning a 2d character array

Tags: c, arrays

This code doesn't scan the whole array. It breaks in the middle

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
int** create(int m)
{
  char **a;
  int i;
  a=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*m);
  for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    *(a+i)=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*m);
  return a;
}
int main()
{
  int i,j,n;
  char **a;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  a = create(n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      scanf("%c",*(a+i)+j);

  printf("Output is \n");
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
      printf("%c",*(*(a+i)+j));
  return 0;
}
```

input given is n = 4
it scans two line and then prints back that two line...
Here is a screenshot of the output
[Output ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybc6q.png)

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code and nothing that can be used as one! A pointer is **not** an array, `char **` is a pointer!

Comment: Thanks for pointing about pointer. All i needed a four letter string for my program. I updated the code. It is working fine.

Comment: Rolled back. Do not edit the question in substantial parts if you got an answer if that leaves the answer without context. Instead you may **append** text to the question.

Comment: Oh, and as we forgot: Don't post images of text, less links therof! See the close-reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of issues in your code. We will address them as we come to them. First, while you are free to allocate storage for `m` pointers and `m` chars per-pointer in a single function, it makes the function very limited in use. You are better served with a function that allocates a given number of bytes and does error checking for you (a `malloc` with error checking if you will), e.g.

```
void *create (size_t s)
{
    void *memptr = calloc (1, s);
    if (!memptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "create() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memptr;
}
```

(**note:** `calloc` is used above to initialize all characters and pointers to `0, NULL` to prevent a read from an uninitialized value if less than all characters are input.)

Your variable type of `int` is fine, but not optimal as `malloc` expects `size_t` (and since array indexes cannot be negative, it makes more sense for all)

```
    size_t i, j, n = 0;
    char **a = NULL;
```

You must *validate* each use of `scanf`, otherwise, you have no way of knowing if your code is processing garbage from this point forward. Always, *always* validate user input. Further, after the user presses <kbd>[Enter]</kbd>, you will be left with a `'\n'` in the *input-buffer* (`stdin`) that you must account for before calling `scanf` for the first character. (a better choice for character-input would be `getchar()`). You can use the `'*'` *assignment suppression* operator for `scanf` to *read & discard* the trailing `'\n'`. e.g.

```
    printf ("\n enter number of pointers to create: ");
    if (scanf (" %zu%*c", &n) != 1) { /* strip \n from input buf */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid unput.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Next, since `create` is a useful allocation funciton that will allocate one block of memory per-call, you simply need to call `create` for each block of memory you need. e.g.

```
    a = create (n * sizeof *a);   /* allocate mem for n pointers */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = create (n);        /* allocate n chars per-ponter */
```

Reading your data presents the same problem you faced with the `'\n'` above. You need some way to account for it and remove it or `scanf ("%c", ...)` will happily accept a `'\n'` as your next input. You can enter your characters all on one line, or you can actually check for the presence of `'\n'` and ignore it as shown below:

```
    printf (" enter (%zu x %zu) chars ('\\n' ignored)\n", n, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {     /* read (n x n) chars into 'a' */
        int c;
        for (j = 0; j < n && (c = getchar()) != EOF;) {
            if (c != '\n')        /* if c is not '\n' add to 'a' */
                *(*(a + i) + j++) = c;
        }
        if (c == EOF) break;      /* bail if EOF encountered */
    }
```

Finally, in any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. When you are done with the memory you have allocated, `free` it. e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)       /* free all allocated memory */
        free (*(a + i));
    free (a);

    return 0;
}
```

Putting all pieces of the puzzle together, you could write your code similar to the following:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

void *create (size_t s)
{
    void *memptr = calloc (1, s);
    if (!memptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "create() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memptr;
}

int main (void ) {

    size_t i, j, n = 0;
    char **a = NULL;

    printf ("\n enter number of pointers to create: ");
    if (scanf (" %zu%*c", &n) != 1) { /* strip \n from input buf */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid unput.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    a = create (n * sizeof *a);   /* allocate mem for n pointers */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = create (n);        /* allocate n chars per-ponter */

    printf (" enter (%zu x %zu) chars ('\\n' ignored)\n", n, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {     /* read (n x n) chars into 'a' */
        int c;
        for (j = 0; j < n && (c = getchar()) != EOF;) {
            if (c != '\n')        /* if c is not '\n' add to 'a' */
                *(*(a + i) + j++) = c;
        }
        if (c == EOF) break;
    }

    printf ("\n output is \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            putchar (*(*(a + i) + j));
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)       /* free all allocated memory */
        free (*(a + i));
    free (a);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Entering all characters as a single line of input

```
$ ./bin/create

 enter number of pointers to create: 4
 enter (4 x 4) chars ('\n' ignored)
catsdogsmiceflea

 output is
cats
dogs
mice
flea
```

Entering `n` characters per line

```
$ ./bin/create

 enter number of pointers to create: 4
 enter (4 x 4) chars ('\n' ignored)
cats
dogs
mice
flea

 output is
cats
dogs
mice
flea
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an unintitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/create
==7034== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7034== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7034== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7034== Command: ./bin/create
==7034==

 enter number of pointers to create: 4
 enter (4 x 4) chars ('\n' ignored)
cats
dogs
mice
flea

 output is
cats
dogs
mice
flea
==7034==
==7034== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7034==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7034==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 48 bytes allocated
==7034==
==7034== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7034==
==7034== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7034== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Always confirm *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and equally important *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*.

Look over the answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Just curious, would you suggest VLAs?

Comment: VLA's are fine, they can be quirky on portability to those on windows depending on which VS version they have. I use them regularly, but you need to make sure you initialize the values with `memset` or the like because you cannot provide an initializer to a VLA when it is declared. Other than that, they are just arrays -- work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
  scanf("%c",*(a+i)+j);
```

When `i` is 1 and `j` is 2, which element is this accessing?

What about when `i` is 2 and `j` is 1?

Answer (score -1):

a is a char and cant be added to an integer even if it contains a number so you have to convert it to an integer to use a+i, to do so you can use atoi()  function and include string.h library.

atoi() takes a string as an input but doesn't work properly if the string contains characters the string must contain numbers.

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        char a;
        int x;
        a='4';
        x=atoi(a);//now you can use x to add it to an integer  
   }
```

As bob said a is a char and the return of the function is int so you cant't use return a;

Comment: In OP code `a` is a `char**` and you can add an integer to a pointer. You can actually add a char to an integer too..

Comment: i tried to add char to int , the compiler gives error. what you said about adding int to pointer is true and thanks for correcting that for me. but adding int to char doesn't work

Comment: Try [again](https://ideone.com/ER4t9Y)...